# Spinner.setadapter on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, sql, spinners

O *array* de jogadores é preenchido com os dados mas dá erro no método `setadapter`.

```
Spinner spinnerJogador1;

   ArrayList<JogadorModel> jogadores = jogadorRepository.SelecionarDisponiveis();

dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, jogadores);

        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);    
        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinnerJogador1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Comment: Olá, provavelmente o seu spinner esta nulo,  por favor consegue postar o log do erro ?

Comment: @UltraSeven coloque o código do Spinner para facilitar a ajuda! :D

Comment: 07-04 06:39:39.512 4198 4198 E     AndroidRuntime                               FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-04 06:39:39.512 4198 4198 E     AndroidRuntime                               Process: com.mycompany.MarcaTimeVolei, PID: 4198
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity Log do erro: ComponentInfo{com.mycompany.MarcaTimeVolei/com.mycompany.MarcaTimeVolei.MontarDuplaActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference

Comment: Olá @ArthurCordovaStapassoli, o log do erro está no comentário anterior.

Comment: Olá @mauriciocaserta. O código está completo, ainda não inseri o códio para capturar a escolha do usuário.

Comment: @UltraSeven me referi ao código referente ao "spinnerJogador1", poderia colar o código em que atribui valor a essa variável?

Comment: @UltraSeven verificou no debug se a variável spinnerJogador1 esta nula ?

Comment: Inseri na pergunta a declaração do spinner.

Comment: @arthur o spinner está com valor nulo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@UltraSenven vc precisa atribuir a váriavel spinnerJogador1 o componente Spinner que você colocou na view, tente assim:

**sua_view.xml**

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/id_do_seu_spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**SuaActivity.java**

```
Spinner spinnerJogador1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.id_do_seu_spinner);
```

Comment: Funcionou! Muito obrigado. Agora estou a pesquisar como capturar o id do jogador selecionado.

Comment: Legal, se você usa uma lista pode fazer dentro do Adpter dele. Abraço, se puder pontuar a resposta eu agradeço, abraço!

Comment: Obrigado. Eu uso adapter com base em exemplos, mas confesso que este assunto ainda é muito confuso para mim, e infelizmente não só este mas vários outros.